# When streaming data from Kafka within Databricks (PySpark), how can I print the consumed message instantly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks

I've created a Kafka topic to produce data to. I've then created a `spark.readStream` to read data from my Kafka topic in Databricks using PySpark. The streamer/consumer is created perfectly, but I cannot figure out how to print out each message consumed without creating a `spark.writeStream`. For example,

```
data = (
   spark.readStream
   ...  (all of my kafka options)
)

display(data)
```

I'd like this display to show each message consumed in an unbounded table or just printed out instead of having to do a writeStream and querying that from memory. Is this possible and can someone assist?

Comment: First question - why do you need them printed out? What is the use case for that?

Comment: @AlexOtt It's for a user demo, to show the idea of "consuming data" within databricks for less technical folk. It'd be nice to be able to display the data right off this stream to avoid further questions about writing and memory. Also, there is some use for confirmation.

Comment: that's why you can do `display(streaming_df)`. Also, take into account that there is a limit on the max output inside notebook... Plus, because processing is running on executor nodes, the print will output on them, and it will be shown only inside the executor logs

Comment: That being said, you will want to write instead to DBFS or a database, then show the output from there since it will be a centralized location